# background image resize after hidding bars

Tags: android, image, background, size, surfaceview

I am making a game. Im using LinearLayout as my main layout, inside i have SurfaceView which implements SurfaceHolder.Callback .

I did load map as image into linearLayout background. Map did resize and fit to my screen. Thats great then i had idea to load that scretch image:

```
MyLinearView.getBackground()
```

When i load that i create some 2 dimension table and create some place to work on my collision checks.

That a part of project which I did great but i had idea to hide my navigate bars and status bars(top bars) so i could make that game fullscreen only. 
I did it like that :

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions)
```

But now when i load my image, it is same size like before(but bigger size of game) so i have problems with null pointers.

How can i load a "good" image ?

Comment: In my opinion , putting  `private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN_OLDER_DEVICES;` (in the hider flag declaration) to hide your action/status bars is the most reliable way to do so. I've used it myself and had no problems with it. To be honest, I dont know what your code is doing to hide your bars so I'm not completely certain that this will help, but at least you save 5 lines of code :p  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762418/how-to-make-action-bar-in-android-full-screen-activity-always-visible/29464813#29464813 <<link for what im suggesting

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work for me :/